# jsonlite Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text

Tags: r, json

I'm trying to read JSON data into R from a string, which is valid JSON data according to https://jsonlint.com/.  However, I'm running into an error parsing it. I've tried **jsonlite**, **RJSONIO**, and **rjson** with no success.

```r
ex <- "{\"promptImageScale\":\"\",\"standardSetLvl\":\"unknown\",\"prompt\":\"A) Thank you\" Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam.\"}"

jsonlite::fromJSON(ex)
#> Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
#>           own","prompt":"A) Thank you" Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam
#>                      (right here) ------^
RJSONIO::fromJSON(ex)
#> Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments, : Invalid JSON Node
rjson::fromJSON(ex)
#> Error in rjson::fromJSON(ex): unexpected character: S
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If I take out the quote before Thank you, `\"`, it works, but I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work as-is (this is just a small part of a much larger problem where I have this issue a few times, and it's not something I can really edit by hand to fix).

```r
ex2 <- "{\"promptImageScale\":\"\",\"standardSetLvl\":\"unknown\",\"prompt\":\"A) Thank you Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam.\"}"

jsonlite::fromJSON(ex2)
#> $promptImageScale
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> $standardSetLvl
#> [1] "unknown"
#> 
#> $prompt
#> [1] "A) Thank you Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam."
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

Comment from @akrun asked whether it was just because of the mismatched quote. This doesn't appear to be the case, however, because if I read in `ex2` from above (where I manually removed the mismatched quote), add the quote back in, write the JSON to a new variable, and then read that in, it works without a problem.

```r
ex2 <- "{\"promptImageScale\":\"\",\"standardSetLvl\":\"unknown\",\"prompt\":\"A) Thank you Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam.\"}"

json_in <- jsonlite::fromJSON(ex2)
json_in$prompt <- gsub("A) Thank you Sam.", 'A) Thank you" Sam.', json_in$prompt)

json_out <- jsonlite::toJSON(json_in)
jsonlite::fromJSON(json_out)
#> $promptImageScale
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> $standardSetLvl
#> [1] "unknown"
#> 
#> $prompt
#> [1] "A) Thank you\" Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam."
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Isn't this because of the quote is not paired i.e. in the second case `"A) Thank you Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam."` the quote before A) ends as Sam. where as in the first, it ends at Thank you and then the last one after the Sam. is without a closing "

Comment: Yeah I guess that's what it's got to be. Maybe I can figure out a regex to take care of that... I'll look into the others I was having issues with and see if that's what it is for all of them.

Comment: I'm now not sure it is becuase of the mismatched quote. Edited the question to show more detail.

Comment: Is the `ex2` you updated shows unmatched quote.  If I check with `cat` ,it is not the case though `cat(ex2)
{"promptImageScale":"","standardSetLvl":"unknown","prompt":"A) Thank you Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam."}`

Comment: whereaas in the ex, it is `cat(ex)#
{"promptImageScale":"","standardSetLvl":"unknown","prompt":"A) Thank you" Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam."}`

Comment: Yes, and `ex2` reads in fine. But if I then write it out with the  mismatched quote, it reads in fine (see the edit above). You can also see the mismatched quote with `cat(json_out) {"promptImageScale":[""],"standardSetLvl":["unknown"],"prompt":["A) Thank you\" Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam."]}`.

Comment: So I guess it's just not clear to me why `jsonlite::fromJSON(json_out)` works above, but `jsonlite::fromJSON(ex)` does not.

Comment: The toJSON also adds the `[]`

Comment: Ah... yes, I see that now. So maybe I can write a script that adds `[]` to each of them. Thank you!

Comment: You can remove it with `json_out <- jsonlite::toJSON(json_in, auto_unbox = TRUE)`, but it still works, may be some other difference

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes, it looks like if I run `jsonlite::toJSON()` prior to `jsonlite::fromJSON()` it all works as I'd hope.

Comment: I think the issue may be how `toJSON` creates the quotes.  if you check with `cat` only the one after Thank you. is escaped. where as in `ex` it is all double quotes and escaped.

Comment: It is the `class` json, that does some formatting, check the `dput` i.e. `> dput(json_out)
structure("{\"promptImageScale\":\"\",\"standardSetLvl\":\"unknown\",\"prompt\":\"A) Thank you\\\" Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam.\"}", class = "json")
> dput(ex)
"{\"promptImageScale\":\"\",\"standardSetLvl\":\"unknown\",\"prompt\":\"A) Thank you\" Sam. [prgrph] B) Thank you> Sam. [prgrph] C)    Thank you, Sam.\"}"`

Comment: Look at the `\\\` before the `"` in json_out

Comment: Yep, I see that now. I'm trying this on my actual use case now and I'm not quite there yet but I think I have enough to go on now. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah actually it doesn't seem to work as I'd hoped. I still need to read it in before I can write it out. Wrapping it in `jsonlite::toJSON()` prior to `jsonlite::fromJSON()` just puts the entire thing in one JSON entry, which it then unwraps. I'll keep messing with it though. Appreciate your help.